# Snap: error: too early for operation, device not yet seeded or device model not acknowledged

Tags: snap, alma-linux

I am trying to automate the installation of `mysql-workbench-community` and `postman` via `snap`. However, when I run `snap install mysql-workbench-community --classic`, I get the error `error: too early for operation, device not yet seeded or device model not acknowledged`

If I try running running `snap install mysql-workbench-community --classic` a second or third time, it eventually installs.

As a workaround for now, I have created a loop which checks whether the `snap` is installed and break out of the loop if it is installed. If it isn't installed, it will attempt to install the `snap` 30 times before failing.

Script is as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

counter=0

dnf install epel-release -y
dnf install snapd -y
if [ ! -L /snap ]; then
        ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap
fi
systemctl enable --now snapd.socket



echo -n "Installing MySQL Workbench ... "
while true
do
        if snap list 2>/dev/null |  grep -q mysql-workbench-community; then 
                break
        else
                snap install mysql-workbench-community --classic
                let "counter+=1"
                sleep 5
        fi

        if [ $counter = 30 ]; then
                exit 10
        fi

done
echo "OK"


snap connect mysql-workbench-community:password-manager-service
snap connect mysql-workbench-community:ssh-keys

echo -n "Installing Postman ... "
while true
do
        if snap list 2>/dev/null |  grep -q postman; then 
                break
        else
                snap install postman --classic
                let "counter+=1"
                sleep 5
        fi

        if [ $counter = 30 ]; then
                exit 10
        fi
done
echo "OK"
```

I am curious as to why I have to install the `snap` a few times before it works and what can be done so I don't need to create the loop.